# Need help performance tuning a query

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, performance-tuning

Basically, here is the design of the table (the part that is necessary):

```
id | dt
--------
1  | 2014-05-13
2  | 1900-01-01
3  | 1900-01-01
4  | 2014-05-12
5  | 1900-01-01
```

So what I am trying to do is to set the `1900-01-01` dates to the data from the above column that is not populated with `1900-01-01`.  So the final data would look like this:

```
id | dt
--------
1  | 2014-05-13
2  | 2014-05-13
3  | 2014-05-13
4  | 2014-05-12
5  | 2014-05-12
```

There are about 500,000 records being done at a time and it's about 50/50 whether it is a real date or `1900-01-01`.  Some of them may have 1 date that goes into 100 `1900-01-01` rows.

Right now, this is what I am working with:

```
UPDATE ISWFN
SET dt = ISWFN2.dt
FROM imp.TBL_DATA ISWFN
JOIN (
        SELECT ISWFN.id, MAX(ISWFN2.id) [id2]
        FROM imp.TBL_DATA ISWFN
            JOIN imp.TBL_DATA ISWFN2 ON
                ISWFN.id > ISWFN2.id
        WHERE ISWFN.dt = '1900-01-01'
            AND ISWFN2.dt != '1900-01-01'
        GROUP BY ISWFN.id ) SQ ON
    ISWFN.id = SQ.id
JOIN imp.TBL_DATA ISWFN2 ON
    SQ.id2 = ISWFN2.id
```

The problem here is that I end up with a nested loop join with 250,000 records on each side of the join, it makes a row estimate of around 62,500,000,000...

Right now, I have `id` as the primary key.  There is also a filtered index on `dt` where it is `1900-01-01` and an opposite filtered index where it is not `1900-01-01`.

Any thoughts?

Edit: it is really the sub-query (SQ) that is the problem area.  That is the part I am trying to tune.

Sorry I don't know how to upload a file... here is the xml for the query plan (for the subquery):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="1.1" Build="10.50.4000.0">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="253776" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="177777" StatementText="Statement1" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x6854D7EBB9341CB2" QueryPlanHash="0xB8F343C168320FED">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="32" CompileTime="34" CompileCPU="18" CompileMemory="408">
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="0.362533" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="253776" LogicalOp="Gather Streams" NodeId="0" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="177777">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
              </OutputList>
              <Parallelism>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="0.21571" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="253776" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="1" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="177776">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <StreamAggregate>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ScalarString1">
                          <Aggregate AggType="MAX" Distinct="false">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="partialagg1005" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <GroupBy>
                      <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                    </GroupBy>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="3.36699" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="507553" LogicalOp="Repartition Streams" NodeId="2" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Parallelism" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="177776">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="partialagg1005" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <Parallelism PartitioningType="Hash">
                        <PartitionColumns>
                          <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                        </PartitionColumns>
                        <OrderBy>
                          <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                            <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                          </OrderByColumn>
                        </OrderBy>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="9802.32" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="507553" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="3" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="177773">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                            <ColumnReference Column="partialagg1005" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <StreamAggregate>
                            <DefinedValues>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Column="partialagg1005" />
                                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ScalarString2">
                                  <Aggregate AggType="MAX" Distinct="false">
                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                      <Identifier>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias2" Column="Column1" />
                                      </Identifier>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                  </Aggregate>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </DefinedValue>
                            </DefinedValues>
                            <GroupBy>
                              <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                            </GroupBy>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="136577" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="32674000000" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="4" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="167970">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias2" Column="Column1" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                                <Predicate>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ScalarString3">
                                    <Compare CompareOp="GT">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias2" Column="Column1" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Compare>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Predicate>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.139637" EstimateIO="0.178475" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="253742" LogicalOp="Index Seek" NodeId="5" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.318111" TableCardinality="511279">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                    <DefinedValues>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column1" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                    </DefinedValues>
                                    <Object Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Index="Index1" Filtered="true" Alias="Alias1" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                                    <SeekPredicates>
                                      <SeekPredicateNew>
                                        <SeekKeys>
                                          <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                                            <RangeColumns>
                                              <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias1" Column="Column2" />
                                            </RangeColumns>
                                            <RangeExpressions>
                                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ScalarString4">
                                                <Const ConstValue="Value1" />
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </RangeExpressions>
                                          </Prefix>
                                        </SeekKeys>
                                      </SeekPredicateNew>
                                    </SeekPredicates>
                                  </IndexScan>
                                </RelOp>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.0464568" EstimateIO="0.01" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="253741" EstimateRows="257537" LogicalOp="Lazy Spool" NodeId="6" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Table Spool" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="11788.5">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias2" Column="Column1" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <Spool>
                                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.283448" EstimateIO="0.183866" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="257537" LogicalOp="Index Scan" NodeId="7" Parallel="true" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.467313" TableCardinality="511279">
                                      <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias2" Column="Column1" />
                                      </OutputList>
                                      <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                                        <DefinedValues>
                                          <DefinedValue>
                                            <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Alias="Alias2" Column="Column1" />
                                          </DefinedValue>
                                        </DefinedValues>
                                        <Object Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Table1" Index="Index2" Filtered="true" Alias="Alias2" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                                      </IndexScan>
                                    </RelOp>
                                  </Spool>
                                </RelOp>
                              </NestedLoops>
                            </RelOp>
                          </StreamAggregate>
                        </RelOp>
                      </Parallelism>
                    </RelOp>
                  </StreamAggregate>
                </RelOp>
              </Parallelism>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Please post an execution plan as well.

Comment: How can I upload a file?  I can't post xml (it doesn't show up)

Comment: Got it, sorry for the long one liner =(

Comment: It's more of a guess but I think a cursor-based solution may be a valid option for this in 2008 version - without the `LAG` function and the other analytic enhancements of 2012.

Comment: Maybe a while loop that updates the records where id = id + 1 until there are no 1900's left?  As much as I dislike loops, I would think this would do a max of 100 iterations based on my data.

Comment: Anyway, the query you have seems over-complicated, joining the table to itself 4 times. It could be simplified, for example `UPDATE iswfn SET dt = (SELECT TOP (1) dt FROM iswfn AS b WHERE b.id < iswfn.id AND b.dt > '19000101' ORDER BY b.id DESC) WHERE dt = '19000101';`

Comment: Good idea, I'll give those 2 options a try tomorrow and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: PS - will the > '1900-01-01' perform better than the != '1900-01-01' or are they the same?  If you don't know off the top of your head, I will test it.

Comment: @ypercube - if you put your (SELECT TOP (1) query as an answer, I will mark this complete.  It literally took 1 second to run and display 250,000 records that needed dates updated and the full update was about 10 second.  This is compared to 30+ minutes (i never got it to complete, at 30 minutes, I gave up) for my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible simplification of the `UPDATE` statement that doesn't join the table to itself so many times. The query plan (at SQL-Fiddle, with small number of rows) is a clustered index scan with a clustered index seek for the subquery:

```
UPDATE iswfn 
SET dt = ( SELECT TOP (1) dt 
           FROM iswfn AS b  
           WHERE b.id < iswfn.id 
             AND b.dt > '19000101' 
           ORDER BY b.id DESC
         ) 
WHERE dt = '19000101';
```

Seems to be good enough for the OP's situation. There is possibly some rewriting that produces an even better execution plan.

Comment: This is definitely working far better than the original query.  The biggest cost is the clustered index update and I think I will see than cost no matter what so very nicely done!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked some days ago on SO ([Replace NULL with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574193/replace-null-with-values)).
The question on SO was with SQLServer 2012, the `CTE` as been modified to take in account the difference in the `OVER` clause between the two versions.

A `SELECT` command that change the rows were the default date is present is

```
WITH Block AS (
  SELECT t1.ID
       , t1.dt
       , dtBlockID = SUM(CASE WHEN t2.dt = '1900-01-01' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
  FROM   Table1 t1
         INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
  GROUP BY t1.id, t1.dt
)
SELECT ID
     , dt = MAX(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY dtBlockID)
FROM   Block
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57b52/9) demo

If the performance are good enough in your system you can easily derive the `UPDATE`

Comment: The performance on this query is actually worse than the original =(  I gave up at 30 minutes, just like my original, but the estimated plan showed 70% for this and 30% for my original.  Anyways, an answer was found in @yper's comment.  Thanks for trying!